# to change sentence to not be dismissive

Tags: phrases

how to phrase "if there is nothing else" without being dismissive.  we want a positive statement that will make the other person respond

Tried
is there anything else is can assist you with

Comment: What happened when you tried *Is there any thing else...*?

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

> Is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> If you have any other inquiries...